# Using TableLayout, Button is going off edge

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, text

I'm trying to make a TableLayout programatically, and my first row `calling` is fine. But in my second row `geo`, the button `openGeo` is going off the right edge of the screen, even though I tried to use the same weighting logic as I did for the first row (`Button` takes whatever space it needs, `EditText`s take the rest)

I've also tried

- Removing the weights from the `EditText`s --> same problem
- Adding the weight to the button `openGeo` --> same problem
- Rearranging order (the button comes first, then the `EditText`s) --> fixes the going off edge issue, but I want the button at the end

So I know the screen is capable of supporting all 5 of these `View`s because rearranging the order doesn't push an `EditText` off the edge. How can I maintain this order, but make it fit like it should?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interact_ui);

    TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.interactUILayout);
    TableRow calling = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow geo = new TableRow(this);

    final EditText number = new EditText(this);
    number.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    number.setHint("###-###-####");

    Button call = new Button(this);
    call.setText("Call");
    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            call(number.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    final EditText address = new EditText(this);
    address.setHint("Address");

    final EditText street = new EditText(this);
    street.setHint("Street");

    final EditText city = new EditText(this);
    city.setHint("City");

    final EditText state = new EditText(this);
    state.setHint("State");

    Button openGeo = new Button(this);
    openGeo.setText("Maps");
    openGeo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openGeo(address.getText().toString(),street.getText().toString(), city.getText().toString(), state.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    calling.addView(number, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    calling.addView(call);
    geo.addView(address, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    geo.addView(street, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    geo.addView(city, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    geo.addView(state, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
    geo.addView(openGeo);
    layout.addView(calling);
    layout.addView(geo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for some items going outside might be because some texts are longer than others hence occupying more space. For weights to work properly, use layout width of `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion when I get home but would you mind explaining the reasoning behind this? All of my `View`s fit if I place the button first so I don't see why it should run out of space if I don't. And also should I always heed this rule in the future that width should be 0 if using weights? Thanks to you